# QT C++ How can I parse the data sent from the serial port?

Tags: c++, qt, parsing

I am trying to read ID over serial port. When I send my `WT+12300` command via serial port. I am getting ID data. But it comes all the time and it doesn't come as parsed. `"WT+,ID,2,3,4,5,6,ASDSA,1,\r\nWT+,ID,2,3,4,5,6,ASDSA,1,\r\nWT+,ID,2, I get it as 3,4,5,6,ASDSA,1,\r\n...` and it keeps going. I just want to take the ASDSA part and display it with a qlabel. How can I do that?
here is function

```
void productDetail::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    if (serial.begin(QString("COM6"), 9600, 8, 0, 1, 0, false)  )
    {
        QString sendWC= "WR+11300";
        serial.send(sendWC);
        QString serialID = serial.getString();
        serialID = serialID.simplified();
        ui->idLabel->setText(serialID);
        qDebug()<< serialID;    
     }
```

Comment: [`QString.split()` might be what you are looking for?](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#split) Split by `,` and take the eighth entry in the `QStringList`.

Comment: Okay, first things first. What type is `serial`? Is it an instance of `QSerialPort`? If so, that's strange, because that class doesn't have a `getString` method. What's more, you usually wait until you get a `readyRead` and start reading from the port then.

Comment: Yes `QSerIalPort`. I'm using [QtSerialMonitor](https://github.com/mich-w/QtSerialMonitor).  I used the functions included in this project.